# npm link not work as I expect but can see node module updated

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-link

Hi I plan to test my node module from local;
I navigate to the folder I need to link and did

```
npm link
```

This created a symlink locally.
Then I navigate my project and did

```
npm link @account/api
```

Then I see the node module @accout/api under my project has been updated, I checked the /src, and it had my updates.

But after I run "npm run dev", I didn't see my update, it still used previous code. Any ideas about this issue?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After updating node modules sometimes the changes are not implemented.
You can try some of below process-

1. Check for the changes after restarting your PC.
2. If after restarting it doesn't work, try to clear npm cache using command below

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Or you can manually delete npm cache from your PC.